# Which one is my real python interpreter (vsc)?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I was reading vsc for python tutorial and I read this
“On Windows, make sure the location of your Python interpreter (that is, the folder where it's installed, like c:\python32) is included in your PATH environment variable. You can check the location by running path at the command prompt. If the Python interpreter's folder isn't included, open Windows Settings, search for "environment", select Edit environment variables for your account, then edit the Path variable to include that folder.”

And I found two interpreter in my computer

one is 'interpreter-cpython37' and its in *pycache* folder

second one is 'interpreter' folder and it contains *pycache*, _import, *init*, dunder_lookup, objectmodel.

what is real interpreter???

I know cpython is made in c language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Linking the original article/instructions by Microsoft here [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments)

You can manually specify the python interpreter using the workspace `settings.json` file. I would highly recommend to do so, as it will contain the project specific dependencies within project root directory. This way you don't end up messing the python installation which is system wide.

On Windows, I would recommend you install [Anaconda Python](https://www.anaconda.com/distribution/). It's a python distribution which comes with a lot of packages installed by default which otherwise might require you some/lot of work to install on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

The folder names you mention aren't standard Python installation locations.

Inside a Python session, do this (your output won't be the same).

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.version
'3.7.2 (tags/v3.7.2:9a3ffc0492, Dec 23 2018, 23:09:28) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)]'
>>> sys.executable
'C:\\Program Files\\Python37\\python.exe'
```

If the Python version agrees with what you expect, then the executable is the one you want. Check your `PATH` environment variable to ensure that it includes the right folder.